# Error converting data type nvarchar to real

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, numeric, nvarchar

I need to subtract two nvarchar values and store the result in another column. I understand that first I need to convert nvarchar to numeric values, but I always get this error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to real

Just to mention in varchar values are stored only numeric values but I can't seem to get this conversion right.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show the code the you are using for the conversion.

Comment: Hi. What is the exact error and on which value does it occur?

Comment: TRY_CONVERT (float, [ep.NovcanaKaznaUkupno]) - TRY_CONVERT (float, [eu.UplataNovcanaKaznaIznos])  As NKPreostalo    this gives me error converting data type nvarchar to real

Comment: Help others help you. Reduce your problem is something others can help you with and post the statement you are actually executing that produces the error. And post examples of your data. And this will inevitably lead to a discussion about why you chose to store numbers as strings - which is the problem you should correct if possible. So specify that if that option is possible. If it is not, then say so specifically and perhaps think about why.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SQL Server error.  If so, use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(real, string_col)
```

This returns `NULL` instead of an error if there are conversion issues.

You can find the offending values using:

```
select string_col
from t
where try_convert(real, string_col) is null and
      string_col is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a case statement. It should be something like (t-sql pseudo code inside a SELECT)

```
case when IsNumeric(column1) AND IsNumeric(column2) 
     then cast(column1 as decimal) - cast(column2 as decimal) 
else NULL end as column3
```

This is a classical example of why you shouldn't mix types (nvarchar and decimal in this case), there are all sorts of shananigans - like ('abc' - 5) or (NULL - NULL) or ('five' - '3  '). If this works, it might be a good idea to look at the "NULL" results, as this might give you valuable insights as to what kind of garbage is being collected in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You said that...

> Just to mention in varchar values are stored only numeric values but I
>   can't seem to get this conversion right.

If that is absolutely true, then there's a very high probability that there are 1 or 2 trailing control characters (Tab, Carriage Return, Line Feed, whatever) in the items causing the errors.

Try converting the NVARCHAR values to the MONEY datatype first.  It won't work for leading control characters but it will for trailing control characters.  Obvioussly your original original value doesn't haven more than 4 decimal places, of course.